# Swift system version checking on Ubuntu

Tags: swift, ubuntu

I know Swift has preprocessor directives that check the OS :

```
#if os(iOS)
    ...
#elseif os(OSX)
    ...
#endif
```

But, after searching online, I've found nothing to check is the OS is Ubuntu.
Is there a way of doing that ? I know swift has only recently been working on Ubuntu, so I realize that there may not be a way as of this writing.

Comment: `#if os(Linux)` – Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035180/swift-arc4random-uniformmax-in-linux.

Comment: And documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID538.

Comment: @MartinR ,Thank you do you want to write an answer So I can accepted ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Swift, `#if ... #endif` are not preprocessor statements, but
enclose a ["Conditional Compilation Block"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID538). The valid arguments for the `os()` platform condition
are (currently) documented as

```
macOS, iOS, watchOS, tvOS, Linux
```

Therefore `#if os(Linux)` checks for a Linux platform.
A typical example is

```
#if os(Linux)
import Glibc
#else
import Darwin
#endif
```

to import functions from the C library on both Linux and Apple platforms.